# How to make a sticky list item which will float only within the screen on android?

Tags: android, listview, footer, sticky

There are many solutions for sticky headers and footers. But what i want is to make a sticky item which will be shown on the top of the list first and while scrolling down sticky item will scroll with the list up to the end of the screen not to the end of the list.

So it will float only within the screen. I'm trying to find a solution for 2 days but couldn't find any efficient way to do that.

You can look this example: https://www.numbrs.com/
What I want is to make the text information on the top as a list item which will not go out of the screen in order to better indicate past and future items.

Do you have any solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should hack these projects.

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

"drag-sort-listview" shows a way of creating a copy of list item view that will float. You have to extends `ListView` and overrides `OnDraw(Canvas)` or `dispatchDraw(Canvas)` methods to get the float view be drawn.  **Don't forget** to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` and `invalidate()` to get the view successfully updated.

"QuickReturnListView" shows getting and caching the vertical locations of other list item views. These locations are used as references at which the float view will be siturated. `translateY()` method is used to move the float view.

**Note:** Earlier version of "drag-sort-listview" used to draw the float view by adding in `WindowManager` instead of drawing the view in `ListView` in latest version. Personally I succeeded with the older way but not with the latest version. My problem is `OnDraw()` or `dispatchDraw()` method is not getting called. I can't find why this happened and just finding on SO and google. If you know please tell me.

**Update:** I may misunderstand what you want. I can't test your example because I don't have any iOS device. If I understand you,[this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/) must be the right answer.